# How can I deploy only modified files in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket pipeline code to deploy when the PR to master is merged. The only problem is that everytime the pipeline deploys all the files irrespective of whether they have changed or not. How can I modify this to ensure that only files that are changed are deployed.

```
image: pyguerder/bitbucket-pipelines-php74
pipelines:
branches:
 master:
  - step:
      name: 'Deploy to production'
      deployment: production
      caches:
        - composer
      script:
        - apt-key adv --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com
        - apt-get update
        - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:1.2.1
          variables:
            USER: $SSH_USERNAME
            SERVER: $SERVER_IP
            REMOTE_PATH: $REMOTE_PATH
            LOCAL_PATH: '${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/*'
            SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
```

Answer (score 2):

rsync is the function you want to use, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105143

For that, they have their own pipeline too https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/rsync-deploy